# Why does my ALTER table statement cause syntax error near Alter

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a previously created table and I am trying to make the Primary Key, which is BookingID, auto increment. I have 4 records in the database currently. The SQL function keeps telling me there is a syntax error near ' ALTER' . I am using SQLite if that matters.

```
ALTER TABLE Booking AUTO_INCREMENT=5
```

Comment: What do you expect writing `AUTO_INCREMENT=5`?

Answer (score 1):

Because "alter" in SQLite only lets you rename tables or add columns; it doesn't support what you're trying to do.

For more information, check out the [documentation of ALTER TABLE in SQLite](http://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html):

> SQLite supports a limited subset of ALTER TABLE. The ALTER TABLE command in SQLite allows the user to rename a table or to add a new column to an existing table.

Comment: And even if it did, that would not be the syntax to do it.

Comment: Oh ok. So should I make a new table ? and then make it auto increment?

Comment: Yes, make a new table.